# How to delete/remove a HTML TR block with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, html-table

I have this code on jQuery to add dynamically a tr block and some inputs, it works fine; but the remove function is not working, I will appreciate any help to make it work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1;
function remove_row(indice){
    alert(indice);
    $("#" + indice).remove();
    counter--;
} 
function addTableRow(jQtable){
    jQtable.each(function(){
        var $table = $(this);
        // Number of td's in the last table row
        var n = $('tr:last td', this).length;
        var tds = "<tr id='row_" + counter + "'><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Apellido(s)</strong></td><td><input type='text' name='apellidos_" + counter + "' id='apellidos_" + counter + "' style='width:300px'/></td><td class='requerido'>*</td>  <td class='borde'>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Nombre(s):</strong></td><td align='left'><input type='text' name='nombres_" + counter + "' id='nombres_" + counter + "' style='width:300px'/></td><td class='requerido'>*</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Cédula:</strong></td><td align='left'><select name='pre_ced_" + counter + "' id='pre_ced_" + counter + "'><option selected='selected' value='0'> Seleccione... </option><option value='3'>V</option><option value='4'>E</option></select> - <input type='text' name='suf_ced_" + counter + "' id='suf_ced_" + counter + "'  width='170'/></td><td class='requerido'>*</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Teléfono:</strong></td><td align='left'><input type='text' name='pre_tel1_" + counter + "' id='pre_tel1_" + counter + "' style='width:60px'/> - <input type='text' name='suf_tel1_" + counter + "' id='suf_tel1_" + counter + "' /></td><td class='requerido'>*</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Celular:</strong></td><td align='left'><input type='text' name='pre_tel2_" + counter + "' id='pre_tel2_" + counter + "' style='width:60px'/> - <input type='text' name='suf_tel2_" + counter + "' id='suf_tel2_" + counter + "' /></td><td class='requerido'>*</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Fax/Otro:</strong></td><td align='left'><input type='text' name='pre_tel3_" + counter + "' id='pre_tel3_" + counter + "' style='width:60px'/> - <input type='text' name='suf_tel3_" + counter + "' id='suf_tel3_" + counter + "' /></td><td class='requerido'>&nbsp;</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Correo:</strong></td><td align='left'><input type='text' name='correo_" + counter + "' id='correo_" + counter + "' style='width:300px'/></td><td class='requerido'>*</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Profesión:</strong></td><td align='left'><input type='text' name='profesion_" + counter + "' id='profesion_" + counter + "' style='width:300px'/></td><td class='requerido'>*</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type='button' value='Eliminar Participante' onclick=\"remove_row('row_" + counter + "');\"> <input type='button' value='Mismos Datos Facturación'></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan='5'  class='borde' align='center'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
        if($('tbody', this).length > 0){
            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
        }else {
            $(this).append(tds);
        }
    });
    counter++;
}
</script>
```

And here is my html

```
<form action="inscripcion.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="inscribir" id="inscribir">
      <div id="formdiv">
      <table border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" id="myTable" name="myTable">
      <tr id="row_0">
          <td colspan="5"  class="borde" align="center" >
          Fecha <?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="5"  class="borde" align="center">
          Evento a Inscribirse
          </td>      
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Taller:
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left"><label for="taller"></label>
            <select name="taller" id="taller" style="width:300px" onchange="xajax_cargar(this.value);">
              <option selected="selected" value="0"> Seleccione... </option>
              <?php
do {  
?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row_cursos['idcurso']?>"><?php echo $row_cursos['titulo']?></option>
              <?php
} while ($row_cursos = mysql_fetch_assoc($cursos));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($cursos);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($cursos, 0);
      $row_cursos = mysql_fetch_assoc($cursos);
  }
?>
            </select></td>
          <td class="requerido">*</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Período/Ciudad:
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left">
          <div id="ciudadesyfechas">
            <center>Seleccione Taller Primero</center>
          </div>
          </td>
          <td class="requerido">*</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td colspan="5"  class="borde" align="center">
          Datos a Facturar
          </td>      
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Razón Social:
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left"><label for="razon_social"></label>
            <input type="text" name="razon_social" id="razon_social" style="width:300px"/>

          </td>
          <td class="requerido">*</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          RIF/CI:
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left"><label for="razon_social"></label>
            <label for="pre_rif"></label>
            <select name="pre_rif" id="pre_rif">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">
            Seleccione...
            </option>
            <option value="1">J</option>
            <option value="2">G</option>
            <option value="3">V</option>
            <option value="4">E</option>
          </select> 
            -
            <label for="suf_rif"></label>
          <input type="text" name="suf_rif" id="suf_rif"  style="width:120px"/> 
          -
          <input type="text" name="suf2_rif" id="suf2_rif" style="width:40px"/></td>
          <td class="requerido">*</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Teléfono:
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left">
          <input type="text" name="pre_tel1" id="pre_tel1" style="width:60px"/> 
          - 
          <label for="suf_tel1"></label>
          <input type="text" name="suf_tel1" id="suf_tel1" /></td>
          <td class="requerido">*</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Celular:
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left">
          <input type="text" name="pre_tel2" id="pre_tel2" style="width:60px"/> 
          - 

          <input type="text" name="suf_tel2" id="suf_tel2" /></td>
          <td class="requerido">*</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Fax/Otro:
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left">

          <input type="text" name="pre_tel3" id="pre_tel3" style="width:60px"/> 
          - 

          <input type="text" name="suf_tel3" id="suf_tel3" /></td>
          <td class="requerido">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Dirección:
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left">
          <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" style="width:300px"/>
</td>
          <td class="requerido">*</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Correo:
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left">

          <label for="correo"></label>
          <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" style="width:300px"/>
</td>
          <td class="requerido">*</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="5"  class="borde" align="center">
          Participante(s)
          </td>      
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Apellido(s):
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left">


          <input type="text" name="apellidos_0" id="apellidos_0" style="width:300px"/>
</td>
          <td class="requerido">*</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Nombre(s):
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left">


          <input type="text" name="nombres_0" id="nombres_0" style="width:300px"/>
</td>
          <td class="requerido">*</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Cédula:
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left"><select name="pre_ced" id="pre_ced">
            <option selected="selected" value="0"> Seleccione... </option>

            <option value="3">V</option>
            <option value="4">E</option>
          </select>
            - 
            <label for="suf_ced"></label>
            <input type="text" name="suf_ced_0" id="suf_ced_0"  width="170"/></td>
          <td class="requerido">*</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Teléfono:
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left">
          <input type="text" name="pre_tel1_0" id="pre_tel1_0" style="width:60px"/> 
          - 
          <label for="suf_tel1"></label>
          <input type="text" name="suf_tel1_0" id="suf_tel1_0" /></td>
          <td class="requerido">*</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Celular:
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left">
          <input type="text" name="pre_tel2_0" id="pre_tel2_0" style="width:60px"/> 
          - 

          <input type="text" name="suf_tel2_0" id="suf_tel2_0" /></td>
          <td class="requerido">*</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Fax/Otro:
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left">

          <input type="text" name="pre_tel3_0" id="pre_tel3_0" style="width:60px"/> 
          - 

          <input type="text" name="suf_tel3_0" id="suf_tel3_0" /></td>
          <td class="requerido">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Correo:
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left">


          <input type="text" name="correo_0" id="correo_0" style="width:300px"/>
</td>
          <td class="requerido">*</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right"><strong>
          Profesión:
          </strong></td>
          <td align="left">


          <input type="text" name="profesion_0" id="profesion_0" style="width:300px"/>
</td>
          <td class="requerido">*</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;

          </td>
          <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left"><input type="button" value="Agregar Participante" id="add" name="add" onclick="addTableRow($('#myTable'));"/> <input type="button" value="Mismos Datos Facturación" /></td>
          <td class="requerido">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="borde">&nbsp;
          </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td colspan="5"  class="borde" align="center">
          &nbsp;<input type="hidden" id="num_campos" name="num_campos" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" id="cant_campos" name="cant_campos" value="0" />
          </td>      
      </tr>

      </table>
     <table align="center" border="0">
     <tr>
     <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="button" value="Guardar" /> <input type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" value="Restablecer" />
     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
      </form>
```

---

Solution

Finally I figured it out giving every tr row an index additional to the one generated:

```
function eliminar(index) {

    var r=confirm("¿Seguro Desea Eliminar este Participante?");
    if (r==true)
      {
            for (n = 0; n < 10; n++)
            {
                $('tr#row' + n + "_" + index).remove();
                                counter--;
            }
      }

}

function addTableRow(jQtable){
    jQtable.each(function(){
        var $table = $(this);
        // Number of td's in the last table row
        var n = $('tr:last td', this).length;
        var tds = "<tr id='row0_" + counter + "'><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Apellido(s)</strong></td><td><input type='text' name='apellidos_" + counter + "' id='apellidos_" + counter + "' style='width:300px'/></td><td class='requerido'>*</td>  <td class='borde'>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr  id='row1_" + counter + "'><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Nombre(s):</strong></td><td align='left'><input type='text' name='nombres_" + counter + "' id='nombres_" + counter + "' style='width:300px'/></td><td class='requerido'>*</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr  id='row2_" + counter + "'><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Cédula:</strong></td><td align='left'><select name='pre_ced_" + counter + "' id='pre_ced_" + counter + "'><option selected='selected' value='0'> Seleccione... </option><option value='3'>V</option><option value='4'>E</option></select> - <input type='text' name='suf_ced_" + counter + "' id='suf_ced_" + counter + "'  width='170'/></td><td class='requerido'>*</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr id='row3_" + counter + "'><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Teléfono:</strong></td><td align='left'><input type='text' name='pre_tel1_" + counter + "' id='pre_tel1_" + counter + "' style='width:60px'/> - <input type='text' name='suf_tel1_" + counter + "' id='suf_tel1_" + counter + "' /></td><td class='requerido'>*</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr id='row4_" + counter + "'><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Celular:</strong></td><td align='left'><input type='text' name='pre_tel2_" + counter + "' id='pre_tel2_" + counter + "' style='width:60px'/> - <input type='text' name='suf_tel2_" + counter + "' id='suf_tel2_" + counter + "' /></td><td class='requerido'>*</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr  id='row5_" + counter + "'><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Fax/Otro:</strong></td><td align='left'><input type='text' name='pre_tel3_" + counter + "' id='pre_tel3_" + counter + "' style='width:60px'/> - <input type='text' name='suf_tel3_" + counter + "' id='suf_tel3_" + counter + "' /></td><td class='requerido'>&nbsp;</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr  id='row6_" + counter + "'><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Correo:</strong></td><td align='left'><input type='text' name='correo_" + counter + "' id='correo_" + counter + "' style='width:300px'/></td><td class='requerido'>*</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr  id='row7_" + counter + "'><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><strong>Profesión:</strong></td><td align='left'><input type='text' name='profesion_" + counter + "' id='profesion_" + counter + "' style='width:300px'/></td><td class='requerido'>*</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr  id='row8_" + counter + "'><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type='button' value='Eliminar Participante' onclick=\"eliminar('" + counter + "');\"> <input type='button' value='Mismos Datos Facturación'></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td class='borde'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr id='row9_" + counter + "'><td colspan='5'  class='borde' align='center'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
        if($('tbody', this).length > 0){
            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
        }else {
            $(this).append(tds);
        }
    });
    counter++;
}
```

Here is the function, and now all I need is a hidden value with the total rows.

Comment: Did you try something like this: `$("#table_id: " + indice).remove();`

Comment: Your <tr> have no attribute id in your code: <tr id=\"row_" + counter + "\">

Comment: I did have an id, because i erased a lot of code from there, i erased it, but i put it on again, edited the question

Comment: I tried with $("#table_id: " + indice).remove(); but firefox gives me this error: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #myTable: row_1

Comment: I think the issue is because i have various tr blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated my question with the solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to add event to dynamically added html elements. Assign a class to buttons on which you want to attach remove event.

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function (){

    $(this).remove();
    counter--;
}
```

Comment: Will it be like this? <input type='button' value='Eliminar Participante' class='remove'>

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer as well, please take this code.

Comment: Ok, i just remove the button, but i need to remove the whole tr block

Comment: If you look, i have a  tr id, i need to remove that block dynamically

Comment: You can try $(this).closest('tr').remove();

Comment: Tried with $(this).closest('tr').remove(); and still only deletes the button

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19952/discussion-between-ricardorios-and-adil)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the space between `.remove ();`

`$("#" + indice).remove ();`

should be:

`$("#" + indice).remove();`

Answer (score 0):

Well I still don't see where you are calling that function first of all. There doesn't appear to be any event attached. But let's say you are trigging it somewhere else in an on click event or something similar.

You've assigned the row's ids of 'row_'+counter. So you'll have an id="row_2" or something similar.

You're .remove() function (and Samuel was right about making it .remove()  ) should call

```
$('tr#row_' + index).remove();
```

You can also use .replaceWith("") as per jQuery's docs. They do the same thing.

Comment: Inside from var tds is a button with an onclick event

Comment: It looks like it should be working, but it's hard to such wide code like this. Is the alert being called? If so, then you've probably got a collision with the id. Here's what I would do: if the alert's not being called, add a class to the input button, set `$('input.class_name').live('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault();});` In that function, grab the id  `$(this).attr('id')` and do a  `$(this).parent('tr').replaceWith('')`